# Linq query to return filtered data

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following data structure (apologies in advance as I'm not sure of the best way to represent the data structure in SO).
The following is a list of tables linked (represented by the one to many

```
1
|
8
```

relationship.

```
---------------------
|GlobalListTable:   |
|-------------------|
|Id                 |
|ProductGroupTableId|
|ProductListTypeId  |   
---------------------
         8
         |
         1
---------------------
|ProductGroupTable: |
|-------------------|
|Id                 |
|Name               |
---------------------
         1
         |
         8
---------------------
|ProductTable:      |
|-------------------|
|Id                 |
|Name               |
|ProductGroupTableId|
---------------------
         1
         |
         8
---------------------
|ComponentTable:    |
|-------------------|
|Id                 |
|Name               |
|ProductTableId     |
|ComponentTypeId    |
---------------------
```

The data in it's simplest form would look like this

```
GlobalListTable1
   ProductGroupTable
       ProductTable1
          ComponentTable ComponentTypeId1
          ComponentTable ComponentTypeId2
          ComponentTable ComponentTypeId3
          ComponentTable ComponentTypeId4
        ProductTable2
          ComponentTable ComponentTypeId1
          ComponentTable ComponentTypeId3
       ProductTable3   
          ComponentTable ComponentTypeId3
          ComponentTable ComponentTypeId4
```

What I want to do is to query (in lambda) the data and return the data but filtered by `ProductListTypeId` and `ComponentTypeId`

So for example I have for the first (easy) bit

```
var productListTypeId=1;    
var componentTypeId=4;
var _results=this.Context.GlobalListTable
.Where(i=>i.ProductListTypeId==productListTypeId);
```

I have tried adding

```
.Where(i=>i.ProductGroupTable.ProductTable.ComponentTable.ComponentTypeId == componentTypeId);
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

I would like to pass in (say) the above parameters and have the following returned:

```
GlobalListTable1
   ProductGroupTable
       ProductTable1
          ComponentTable4
       ProductTable3   
          ComponentTable4
```

Edit: Using EntityFramework to retrieve the data

Edit: I'm beginning to think this isn't possible with standard linq queries. The only way I seem to be able to get this working  is to iterate through the query and manually remove the unwanted records.

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework?

Comment: What error do you get / what's the behavior of "not working"?

Comment: @Bob - correct version 6

Comment: @Steven Wexler - the syntax doesn't work. How I've written it is how I envisage it in my head, but the syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I ended up solving the problem.

It doesn't look like I can achieve it using linq alone so I need to iterate through the results and eliminate the unwanted.

My query to get the top level objects:

```
var query = this.Context.GlobalListTable
        .Where(i => i.ProductListTypeId == productListTypeId)
        .Select(i => i.ProductGroupTable)
        .SelectMany(i => i.ComponentTables)
        .Where(t => t.ComponentTypeId == componentTypeId)           
        .ToList();
```

Iterate through the results and exclude the unwanted:

```
foreach (var _globalListTable in query)
{
    foreach (var _productTable in _globalListTable.ProductGroupTable.ProductTables)
    {
        var _exclude = _productTable.ComponentTables.Where(i => i.ComponentTypeId != componentTypeId);
        _productTable.ComponentTables = _productTable.ComponentTables.Except(_exclude).ToList();
    }
}

return query;
```

Works perfectly, if not elegantly.

Comment: Sometimes, I just wouldn't reach for EF first, sometimes it just has to be done in Stored Procs and SQL.

Answer (score 1):

SelectMany'll do the trick, here is the query:

```
var global = new List<GlobalListTable>()
        {
            new GlobalListTable()
            {
                ProductListTypeId = 1,
                ProductGroupTable = new ProductGroupTable()
                {
                    ProductTables = new List<ProductTable>()
                    {
                        new ProductTable()
                        {
                            ComponentTables = new List<ComponentTable>()
                            {
                                new ComponentTable(){ComponentTypeId = 4, Name = "Sucess"}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        var productListTypeId=1;    
        var componentTypeId=4;
        var query =
            global.Where(t => t.ProductListTypeId == productListTypeId)
                .Select(t => t.ProductGroupTable)
                .SelectMany(t => t.ProductTables)
                .SelectMany(t => t.ComponentTables)
                .Where(t => t.ComponentTypeId == componentTypeId);
```

**EDIT**
if you need globalListTable, then query'll look like follow:

```
var query =
            global.Where(t => t.ProductListTypeId == productListTypeId).Where(t1=>t1
                .ProductGroupTable
                .ProductTables
                .SelectMany(t => t.ComponentTables)
                .Any(t => t.ComponentTypeId == componentTypeId));
```

**EDIT2**

```
var filterComp =
                global.Select(t => t.ProductGroupTable)
                    .SelectMany(t => t.ProductTables)
                    .SelectMany(t => t.ComponentTables)
                    .Where(t => t.ComponentTypeId == componentTypeId);
```

I used the poco classes defined like this:

```
internal class GlobalListTable
{
    public ProductGroupTable ProductGroupTable { get; set; }
    public int ProductListTypeId { get; set; }
}

internal class ProductGroupTable
{
    public List<ProductTable> ProductTables { get; set; }
}

internal class ProductTable
{
    public List<ComponentTable> ComponentTables { get; set; }
}

internal class ComponentTable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ComponentTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it just return a IEnumerable<ComponentTable>. I would like IEnumerable<GlobalListTable> with it populated like the example - with only the child records matching the criteria.

Comment: @DeclanMcD Sorry, i misunderstood u, edited my answer

Comment: close, but it still doesn't do the trick. It returns the data in the correct format alright but it is not filtered. i.e. it still returns all the records in the ComponentTable rather than the predicate filter (t.ComponentTypeId == componentTypeId). They way I have it at the moment is to iterate through the list and manually remove all non matching records - very tedious.

Comment: strange how the comments don't appear to accept the text @Alex Voskresenskiy in my previous comments?

Comment: @DeclanMcD, yeah, my fault. See Edit2 for filter. Of course it is not good to perform two separate queries, but i cannot do it better. Don't forget to make ToList in first query so that EF won't make more queries in DB

Comment: I even tried going in at the bottom and selecting up e.g.
`var query =
            this.Context.ComponentTable.Where(t => t.ComponentTypeId == componentTypeId)
    .Select(t=>t.ProductTable);`
but it still lists **all** the ComponentTable records when I examine the list of ProductTable records returned. (but it does only return those ProductTable records that match the predicate at least)

Comment: @DeclanMcDi don't understand, you lack performance on quering ComponentTable rows?

Comment: the EDIT2 still only returns a list of ComponentTable records. The EDIT1 code is the closest, but contains all the unwanted ComponentTable records. I'm beginning to think this isn't possible with linq queries.